# Build an GUI with scenebuilder, how to implement?

Tags: java, netbeans, scenebuilder

I need to build an elevator system. I use netbeans. 
I want to make a GUI design in scenebuilder. But when I added it into our files in netbeans, how do I implement it into code so the buttons and so on have functions?

Comment: For beginners, it's easier to create your project using `NetBeans` and then let [`SceneBuilder`](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) open the file after you double-click on the `.fxml` file. Learn how to use [`GitHub`](https://github.com) if you all are going to be working on different parts of the project.

Comment: Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539792/how-to-separate-a-javafx-appliciation/47540187#47540187) to see how to create an `FXML` project in `NetBeans`. After that, you just double-click the `FXML` file and SceneBuilder should open it.

Comment: To get specific help, you need to post your project's structure, your main class, your fxml file, and your fxml's controller.

Answer (score 0):

Check Tutorial at this link: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/
It explains in simple terms how to create and implement GUI in JavaFX application.

Basically you need to make controller class and link it with gui in scene builder in Controller section and you also need to set id property (Code section) to gui elements.